# Unchecked/unconfirmed cast reported by FindBugs even though there is no cast

Tags: java, generics, casting, findbugs

Consider the following code

```
class AbstractPacket {
}

class ConcretePacket extends AbstractPacket {
}

abstract class AbstractPacketReader<P extends AbstractPacket> {
    P read() {
        return doRead();
    }

    protected abstract P doRead();
}

class ConcretePacketReader extends AbstractPacketReader<ConcretePacket> {
    @Override
    protected ConcretePacket doRead() {
        return new ConcretePacket();
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcretePacketReader reader = new ConcretePacketReader();
        ConcretePacket packet = reader.read(); // Unchecked/unconfirmed cast here
        System.out.println(packet);
    }
}
```

Why should FindBugs complain about unchecked cast? Surely since `ConcretePacketReader` extends `AbstractPacketReader<ConcretePacket>` its `read` function should return `ConcretePacket` and there is no cast needed. Of course there is really a cast because of the type erasure, but that's a kind of cast that the compiler checks for safety, so FindBugs shouldn't care about it.

Is it a bug in FindBugs or am I missing something absurdly simple yet not completely obvious here?

Comment: Looks fine to me, I suspect FindBugs is confused by not finding `read()` in `ConcretePacketReader` and looking from the perspective of `AbstractPacketReader`, in which case the cast would be unchecked. Except it's constrained by the declaration of `ConcretePacketReader`.  Eclipse Neon has no complaints.  I hesitate to post this as an answer as I've not done much Java in the past year so I could be wrong.

Comment: Even if FindBugs doesn’t recognize that the cast is implied, it still isn’t an unchecked cast, as the cast is to the reifiable type `ConcretePacket`. It’s hard to believe that it has such a bug as that is a quite common use case of Generics.